# No Response getting from Curl Request to https server

Tags: php, curl

I am creating a PHP curl request to server and expecting some string in response but no response generating , What may be the reason for that?

Below is the Curl code for the same:

```
$fields = array("username"=> 'xxx',"domain"=> 'xxx',"password" => 'xxx');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://host:8090/add-user"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $usr.':'.$pass);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);    
if(!$result=curl_exec($ch)){ 
    trigger_error(curl_error($ch)); 
} 
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

Below is equivalent command line request for the same:

```
curl --data 'username=xxx&domain=xxx&password=xxx' https://host:8090/add-user -k -v -u 'usr:pass'
```

What i am doing Wrong Here?

Comment: What happens if you var_dump() the curl_error() message?

Comment: getting no response in return and no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first try to use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, $file_handler);` where `$file_handler` = `fopen('somefile.log', 'a')`. Thus you will see what exactly **cURL** does, and where it fails.

Comment: Thanks.. Actually response is returned through headers.. using curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); solved the issue.