# Steps for debugging php Curl on windows

Tags: php, windows, debugging, curl

I had a lot of trouble figuring out why my php Curl API worked fine on a Mac using MAMP, but would not work under windows.

I asked fot debugging tips or useful information for finding curl configuration issues under windows.

The accepted answer contains a list of the steps that helped me get curl working on windows 7 32 bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a list of steps for debugging Curl:

Check in phpinfo module that Curl IS enabled.

Verify extensions dir path is propperly set in php.ini and that extension=php_curl.dll is uncommented.

Check that Environment Variables are propperly set as per: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.addtopath

Run deplister.exe ext\php_curl.dll to verify all dependencies are correctly satisfied.

If all of the above is working then check the output of CURLOPT_VERBOSE. As per @hp95 suggestion in the following thread: [No Response getting from Curl Request to https server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262524/no-response-getting-from-curl-request-to-https-server)

If you are reaching a site that uses SSL check the following post: [HTTPS and SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed, CA is OK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400300/https-and-ssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed-ca-is-ok)

And fix it like these:

https://snippets.webaware.com.au/howto/stop-turning-off-curlopt_ssl_verifypeer-and-fix-your-php-config/

Answer (score 1):

If Curl still doesn't work, you can use file_get_contents to make POST requests. It works on all hostingers, all OS and on local.

```
    $url = 'WhateverUrlYouWant';
    $postdata = http_build_query(
        array(
            'id' => '202',
            'form' => 'animal',
            .....
        )
    );
    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => $postdata
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
    $result = file_get_contents($url,false, $context);
    echo $result
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But I need curl to run an API. The post example is just an oversimplifcation of the problem.

Comment: Maybe : 
    Copy the files libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll in C:\Windows\System32\
    Copy the file php_curl.dll in c:\wamp\bin\php\php[your actual version]\ext\

Comment: Maybe, you simple forget to activate it ;)

    Left-click on the WAMP server icon in the bottom right of the screen
    PHP -> PHP Extensions -> php_curl

Comment: Nope. Curl is enabled.

Comment: It is your case : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262524/no-response-getting-from-curl-request-to-https-server

Answer (score -1):

reverse

- curl_close($curl); 
  print_r($response);
  ** this is a broken protocol **

to

- print_r($response); 
  curl_close($curl);
  ** print your results BEFORE closing, which destroys (empties) the $response **